# Tag Request: desktop-notifications

Tags: feature-request, tags

Would the tag [deskop-notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deskop-notifications) be a good addition? I just asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399204/chrome-desktop-notifications-not-cancelling), and I know of many others that could fit this tag (see **related** of the linked question).

Please note that this is not just a tag-request, but rather asking if this tag would be good.

Comment: Related: what is the purpose of a [notifications] tag? [desktop-notifications] might make sense, [apple-push-notifications] seems eminently reasonable, but who is an expert in [notifications]?

Comment: @CodyGray Yes! I agree... tell me if I'm wrong, but isn't there a tag for each individual **technology**? [tag:notifications] isn't a technology, but [tag:desktop-notifications] or [apple-push-notifications] etc. use different _languages_ and _technologies_. I mean, who is going to look at questions tagged [tag:notifications]? Most questions tagged this way get around **3** views... most agreed :).

Comment: It is not as clear cut as a tag for each technology. But you're right in general, overly-generic tags are not useful. My idea was that the [notifications] tag would be something you could propose for a tag cleanup here on Meta. In the process of doing the clean-up, we could retag questions with more appropriate and specific tags.